# Searching full name or first or last name in MySQL database with first and last name in separate columns

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working with an existing database that has first name and last name seperated in the database. I need to create a function that will take one search input and return results. say my database has a structure like....

```
nameFirst nameLast
Joe       Smith
Joe       Jones
Joe       Brown
```

How could I, using MySql, take a search input that is say 'Joe Smith' and just get his row? But if I put just 'Joe' in the search field, return them all? Will I need to explode the string with a space? thanks!

Comment: do you also need to find 'Smith, Joe', or 'Joseph Smith'?

Comment: Exploding the string is one way to go, but what if there is a middle initial or name involved?

Comment: The searching would most likely be like 'Joe Smith'... also there are some instance in the database where there's .Jrs and such

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE CONCAT( nameFirst,  ' ', nameLast ) LIKE  '%Joe%'
```

Be sure to sanitize any user submitted parameters such as "Joe"

Comment: I used codeigniter activerecord but here's what I ended up using... $term = $search_array['term'];
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM Database WHERE CONCAT( nameFirst,  ' ', nameLast ) LIKE  '%$term%'");

Comment: `fullname` field could be added in database table! It would be much faster.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. When you will have situation that you can not change the table, then this type of query saves your time.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONCAT(nameFirst, ' ', nameLast) LIKE 'Joe%';
```

I suggest to use this if you are sure that your search input start with "Joe" to filter more.

In my humble opinion in a lot of cases we don't know if the search input is the name or the surname so I suggest to use this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONCAT(nameFirst,  ' ', nameLast) LIKE  'SEARCH_INPUT%' OR CONCAT(nameLast,  ' ', nameFirst) LIKE 'SEARCH_INPUT%';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT * from add_contact  WHERE ( CONCAT(first_name, ' ',last_name)  LIKE '%$search%' OR first_name LIKE '%$search%' OR last_name LIKE '%$search%' OR company LIKE '%$search%') AND (archives='$archives') ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(sort_date) DESC";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.